# javascript -- capturing the value entered to use elsewhere

Tags: javascript

I have an image on the page. 
When clicked on that, i am prompting for input and 
writing that value entered on the page.

I've tried the following and some other things around it:

```
<form name="FORM_1" action="post">
...

<input type=text name=x >

...

<p>Click on the image to get enter the value</p>
<a href="", onClick="x=prompt('Enter a number')">
<img src='data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODhgjjhgAAgIAAgACAgICAgMDAwP8AAAD/AP//AAAA//8A/wD//////ywAAAAAIAAgAAAEkfDJSau9OOvNu//gBABJWYYXaa6JNY6ays6tBIjuq+/8fZe3XG8YhNlcCSKvxkP2gLuWMaOKrl7JKZXGPXFGXRPYuxl3seTYQ0bTpSuweBhN1dnCSRPVFlzj33AnfX5hZXyBXFprfXY5LD6MRR5Nh0aKeylTl5gpR4Mxm5WfoIsYoaaDLy4gPmuuoyFEKLO0tREAOw==' alt="Dance?" pagespeed_url_hash="2096625741"> 
</a>

</form>
```

How do I put the value of x to the form field x? What is the best way to do this?

Way too new to javascript.

TIA.

EDIT:

I am getting the entered value properly-- when i replace

```
x=prompt('Enter a number')
```

in the code with

```
alert(prompt('Enter a number'))
```

the value is there.

Comment: The value is stored in x.

Comment: You dont have to use the <a> tag, add an event listener to the image and execute your code there,eg prompt there so you can use the variable later.

Answer (score 0):

`I'm stuck is how to put that value to the form field`

Try this:

```
onClick="x=prompt('Enter a number'); document.getElementsByName('x')[0].value=x;"
```